# Tezos online wallets that can be synchronised with Ledger Nano S

Tags: wallets

Now TezBox is pretty much dormant.  I use Galleon synchronised with my Ledger Nano S.  I would be grateful if anyone could kindly tell me which online Tezos wallet apart from Galleon, if any, can be synchronised with Ledger Nano S.

Many thanks in anticipation.

Kind regards,